# Canvas Fillstyle with MoveTo and LineTo

Tags: canvas

I'm drwing a shape on canvas but I can't fill it idk why :v
I want to fill with any color the shape I did inside the rectangle.

HTML: `<canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>`

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var size = 200;

ctx.rect(500, 50, 200, 200);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(530, 100);
ctx.lineTo(550, 140);

ctx.moveTo(550, 140);
ctx.lineTo(570, 100);

ctx.moveTo(570, 100);
ctx.lineTo(550, 120);

ctx.moveTo(530, 100);
ctx.lineTo(550, 120);

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `moveTo()` method multiple times, which breaks the reference to the previous point of line.

also, you should use `beginPath()` method before drawing the rectangle.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var size = 200;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(500, 50, 200, 200);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(530, 100);
ctx.lineTo(550, 140);
ctx.lineTo(570, 100);
ctx.lineTo(550, 120);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```